# Mostrar precios de oferta en productos con variantes Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

tengo el siguiente codigo php en wordpress para que me muestre el precio precio del producto tachado y el precio de oferta, los productos tienen dos variantes, hay veces que una variante esta en oferta y hay veces que otra, el problema es que en el listado de productos de la tienda me figura el precio de la variante con el precio mas bajo tachado (no el precio de la variante que esta de oferta) y al lado el precio de la oferta si me lo muestra bien, lo mismo pasa en la pagina del producto, por favor necesito ayuda para corregir eso :

```
// Añadir filtros para el precio de venta y el precio regular
add_filter(
  'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html',
  'lw_variable_product_price',
  10, 2
);
add_filter(
  'woocommerce_variable_price_html',
  'lw_variable_product_price',
  10, 2
);

// Función para mostrar el precio regular tachado y el precio de oferta
function lw_variable_product_price($price_html, $product) {
  // Obtener precios de las variantes
  $variation_prices = $product->get_variation_prices(true);

  // Precio regular más alto
  $highest_regular_price = max($variation_prices['regular_price']);

  // Verificar si hay una oferta
  $is_on_sale = $product->is_on_sale();

  // Construir cadena de precio
  if (
    $is_on_sale
    && $highest_regular_price !== $variation_prices['price'][0]
  ) {
    $price_html = '<del>'
      . wc_price($highest_regular_price)
      . $product->get_price_suffix()
      . '</del> <ins>'
      . wc_price($variation_prices['price'][0])
      . $product->get_price_suffix()
      . '</ins>';
  } else {
    $price_html = wc_price($variation_prices['price'][0])
      . $product->get_price_suffix();
  }

  return $price_html;
}
```

Comment: hacete un `print_r` de `$variation_prices` ; tiene que tener una relacion de cada variation con sus precios

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

La función `get_variation_prices()` retorna un array de arrayes, con todos los tipos de precios de las variantes.

Un ejemplo de `print_r($variation_prices, true);` da como resultado:

```
Array
  (
    [price] => Array
      (
        [44583] => 100.00
        [44584] => 110.00
        [44585] => 115.00
        [44586] => 130.00
      )

    [regular_price] => Array
      (
        [44583] => 100.00
        [44584] => 110.00
        [44585] => 120.00
        [44586] => 130.00
      )

    [sale_price] => Array
      (
        [44583] => 100.00
        [44584] => 110.00
        [44585] => 115.00
        [44586] => 130.00
      )
  )
```

Ahí podemos ver que hay 3 tipos de precio, y en cada uno se listan los `id` de la variante con su precio correspondiente. En este caso hay 4 variantes y sólo una está "onsale" es la variación `[44585]` que lista un precio "regular" de `120` y un precio "sale" de `115`.

Como es medio difícil de ver así como viene y manipular los datos para imprimirlos, reconstruimos la data en un array nuevo que nos permita recorrerlo por variación (id) y no por tipo de precio.

Esto tal vez se pueda mejorar, va con `foreach`s para mas claridad:

```
$variation_prices_by_variation_ = [];

foreach ($variation_prices as $price_type => $prices_by_variation) {
  foreach ($prices_by_variation as $variation_id => $variation_price) {
    $variation_prices_by_variation_[$variation_id][$price_type] = $variation_price;
  }
}
```

Este nuevo array se ve algo así:

```
Array
  (
    [44583] => Array
      (
        [price] => 100.00
        [regular_price] => 100.00
        [sale_price] => 100.00
      )

    [44584] => Array
      (
        [price] => 110.00
        [regular_price] => 110.00
        [sale_price] => 110.00
      )

    [44585] => Array
      (
        [price] => 115.00
        [regular_price] => 120.00
        [sale_price] => 115.00
      )

    [44586] => Array
      (
        [price] => 130.00
        [regular_price] => 130.00
        [sale_price] => 130.00
      )

  )
```

Mucho mas manipulable, ahora lo que hacemos es listar cada variante y formateamos el html segun si difieren el precio regular del precio de oferta:

```
$price_html_new = '';
if ($is_on_sale) {
  $all_prices = [];
  foreach ($variation_prices_by_variation_ as $variation_id => $prices) {

// usamos un formato diferente si los precios difieren
    $format_price = ($prices['regular_price'] !== $prices['sale_price'])
      ? '<span class="var-%s isonsale"><del>%s</del> <ins>%s</ins></span>'
      : '<span class="var-%s">%s</span>';
// aplicamos el formato, el "sin sale" ignora los parametros extra
    $all_prices[] = sprintf(
      $format_price,
      $variation_id,
      $prices['regular_price'],
      $prices['sale_price']
    );
  }
// juntamos todos los precios separados por una barra
  $price_html_new = implode(' | ', $all_prices);
}
```

Todo Junto queda algo así:

```php
// Función para mostrar el precio regular tachado y el precio de oferta
function lw_variable_product_price($price_html, $product)
{
  if (!is_admin()) {
    $is_on_sale = $product->is_on_sale();

    // Obtener precios de las variantes
    $variation_prices = $product->get_variation_prices(true);

    $variation_prices_by_variation_ = [];

    foreach ($variation_prices as $price_type => $prices_by_variation) {
      foreach ($prices_by_variation as $variation_id => $variation_price) {
        $variation_prices_by_variation_[$variation_id][$price_type] = $variation_price;
      }
    }

    $price_html_new = '';
    if ($is_on_sale) {
      $all_prices = [];
      foreach ($variation_prices_by_variation_ as $variation_id => $prices) {
        $format_price = ($prices['regular_price'] !== $prices['sale_price'])
          ? '<span class="var-%s isonsale"><del>%s</del> <ins>%s</ins></span>'
          : '<span class="var-%s">%s</span>';
        $all_prices[] = sprintf(
          $format_price,
          $variation_id,
          $prices['regular_price'],
          $prices['sale_price']
        );
      }
      $price_html_new = implode(' | ', $all_prices);
    }


    error_log(
      print_r(
        [
          __FUNCTION__,
          $product->get_name(),
          $variation_prices,
          $variation_prices_by_variation_,
          $price_html,
          $price_html_new,
          $is_on_sale ? 'onsale' : 'not onsale'
        ],
        true
      )
    );
    $price_html = "{$price_html} <br/>\n<!-- new --> {$price_html_new}";
  }
  return $price_html;
}
// Añadir filtros para el precio de venta y el precio regular
add_filter(
  'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html',
  'lw_variable_product_price',
  10,
  2
);
add_filter(
  'woocommerce_variable_price_html',
  'lw_variable_product_price',
  10,
  2
);
```

- en el html devuelto dejo el precio original así se nota cómo es la transformación.

se ve algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- php 8.0
- wordpress 6.4.3
- woocommerce 8.5.2
- theme classic twentyseventeen 3.5